# Program Is Returning Sorted Indexes But The Array Was Never Sorted

Tags: java

My program has a method which allows the user to search for an element in an array and returns its index(es). For some reason it is returning the indexes as they would be if the array was sorted which it never was.

Here is the method:

```
public static ArrayList elementIndex(int search) {

        ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) 
            if (search == array[i]) {

            index.add(i + 1); 

        }
        return index;

    }
```

The only time I sorted an array was in a previous method so I will include that in case it has something to do:

```
public static int mostCommon(int size) {

        int[] arraySorted = array;      
        int mostCommon = 0, mostCommonCount = 0, currentCount = 0;

        Arrays.sort(arraySorted);

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            if (arraySorted[i - 1] == arraySorted[i]) {
                currentCount++;

                if (currentCount > mostCommonCount) {
                    mostCommonCount = currentCount;
                    mostCommon = arraySorted[i];
                }
            }
            else 
                currentCount = 0;

        }

        return mostCommon;
    }
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` is a mutating method -- it (permanently) modifies the array to which it is applied.  If you previously sorted the array it remains sorted later in the program.

Comment: Make a copy using `int[] arraySorted = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);`

Comment: Just curious. Why the +1 in  `i + 1`? I think it should be `index.add(i)`

Comment: So that it looks nicer and would return 1 for the first element instead of 0 @SamuelToh

Comment: @EthanO okay. As long as you know what you are doing that is fine. Because thought you might have miss the fact that array's first index begins as 0 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

`arraySorted` in your code (`mostCommon` method) is a reference to (global) variable `array` - both point to the same object. Therefore what happens to one array, happens to the other as well. I.e. when you sort one, the other (the same array) gets sorted too.